# How to make a beamer template with this format?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, framed

i'm trying to convert a \documentclass{article} into a \documentclass{beamer}, but keeping the structure. The image above is the result I got working with the class article.

[image]

It's exactly what I want, but I can't do much with it since it's not in beamer class...
The code I used to generate it is shown bellow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0in,paperwidth=720pt,paperheight=405pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 \definecolor{color_283006}{rgb}{1,1,1}
 \definecolor{color_29791}{rgb}{0,0,0}
 \definecolor{color_118168}{rgb}{0.34902,0.34902,0.34902}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \path(0pt,0pt);
  \filldraw[color_283006][even odd rule]
  (-15pt, 10pt) -- (682.5pt, 10pt)
  -- (682.5pt, 10pt)
  -- (682.5pt, -382.3438pt)
  -- (682.5pt, -382.3438pt)
  -- (-15pt, -382.3438pt) -- cycle
  ;
 \draw[color_29791,line width=0.726563pt,line join=round]
(247.3314pt, 6.594879pt) -- (659.7076pt, 6.594879pt)
-- (659.7076pt, 6.594879pt)
-- (659.7076pt, -47.85956pt)
-- (659.7076pt, -47.85956pt)
-- (247.3314pt, -47.85956pt) -- cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
 \put(404.4427,-12.62601){\fontsize{12.59375}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m} 
 {n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Título do trabalho}
 \put(431.8171,-27.73849){\fontsize{12.59375}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m} 
 {n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Autores}
 \put(422.0327,-42.85101){\fontsize{12.59375}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m} 
{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Instituições}
 \end{picture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\draw[color_29791,line width=0.726563pt,line join=round]
(9.302652pt, -53.32422pt) -- (659.7076pt, -53.32422pt)
 -- (659.7076pt, -53.32422pt)
 -- (659.7076pt, -370.4121pt)
 -- (659.7076pt, -370.4121pt)
 -- (9.302652pt, -370.4121pt) -- cycle
 ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
 \put(52.27922,-262.5529){\fontsize{35.84375}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m} 
 {n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Página 1: introdução e metodologia}
 \put(643.1647,-361.9257){\fontsize{17.4375}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m} 
 {n}\selectfont\color{color_118168}1}
 \put(10.1875,-50.50934){\includegraphics[width=188.5865pt,height=52.75934pt]{Imagens/oi.png}}
 \end{picture}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

My idea was to configure the header using the code above and do the same with the frames, but I'm not used to beamer...

If someone have some idea, it will be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.